# Update a NuGet Package to latest version even when there's a constraint that prevents the whole action

Tags: .net, dependencies, nuget, updates

For example, I've a solution on which I'm using Castle Windsor that depends on Castle Core. I want to upgrade Castle Windsor to 4.0.0 but Castle Core has a constraint that prevents it: `< 4.0.0`.

How do you force `update` to upgrade a package ignoring version dependency constraints?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you force update to upgrade a package ignoring version dependency constraints?

Do you want to upgrade **Castle.Core** to 4.0.0 rather than **Castle.Windsor**?

If yes, as a workaround for this question, you can install the package Castle.Core 4.0.0 first. Then install the package Castle.Windsor with option "**IgnoreDependencies**" in the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Castle.Windsor -IgnoreDependencies
```

Comment: Nice, I'll give a try

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, Does this answer resolve your question? If not, you can share me the latest status of this question, I will follow it up.

Comment: I don't know yet, because I need to fix some design flaw before I return to this issue.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, how about the result about this issue?

Comment: I had no chance to apply it yet. But don't worry, I appreciate that you're curious about the issue. I'll update it once I've tried it. Sorry.